# yii can't upload file (multipart/form-data isn't set)

Tags: file-upload, yii, multipartform-data

I can't upload image, because enctype of form is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I use this code:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
));
```

And for few file inputs:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($model->scans as $scan) { ?>
    <fieldset>
    ...
    <dd><?php echo $form->fileField($scan,'file_name', array('size'=>'10', 'name'=>get_class($scan).'['.$i.'][file_name]')); ?></dd>
    ...
    </fieldset>
    <?php       $i++;
} ?>
```

After select a file and submit I see Post data in Firebug:

```
enctype - "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

and empty file_name parameter.

```
$_FILES
```

is empty so I can't get file.

So, why isn't `'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')` working?

**update:**
Html source of generated form is right:

```
<form id="yw0" method="post" action="/office/index.php?r=project/profileCreate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
...
<dd>
<input id="ytProfileScan_0_file_name" type="hidden" name="ProfileScan[0][file_name]" value="">
<input id="ProfileScan_0_file_name" type="file" name="ProfileScan[0][file_name]" size="10">
</dd>
...
</fieldset>
```

Comment: what did you see on HTML source on browser ?  does your form tag contains enctype as "multipart/form-data"  ??

Comment: @SuVeRa, yes source is right: `<form id="yw0" method="post" action="/office/index.php?r=project/profileCreate" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that it's EUpdateDialog problem (which I used to render my form). I need to organize ajax upload